# Problem with spring boot api. Response is 404 not found

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm new of spring boot and i'm trying to make a simple api rest service with a method that return a string but I contine to receive 404 on postman
My controller

```
@RestController
public class PhotoController {
    @GetMapping(path = "/api/photos", produces = "application/json")
    public String getAll(){
        return "finito";
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.33</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties

```
debug = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/photos
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql: true
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action=drop-and-create
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target=create.sql
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.drop-target=drop.sql
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format.sql=true
```

I'm not understanding why it do this, I'm sure that url is that and I've added restcontroller in my class (I know that the method should not be implemented in this way but I wanna just make a test)

project structure

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qo86A.png)

Comment: What URL are you requesting, and what do your logs say?

Comment: @tgdavies http://localhost:8080/api/photos my log sy resource not found Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicError

Comment: Can you show your project structure

Comment: @Youans I show my project structure in the photo

Comment: Please show the logs of your app when it starts and show an example `curl` command that fails.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, My take away is that your Spring dependencies are not listed at the same level as the `DemoApplication` class as you show in the project structure image.

You should move the following packages (Controller, Model, Service) to be under the `com.example.demo` package

After that, your controller and mapping will be discovered by Spring Boot discovery service

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/api/photos", produces = "application/json")
```

not name = "/api/photos".

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this isn't the solution

Answer (score 0):

You may try this annotations

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/photos")
public class PhotoController {
    @GetMapping
    public String getAll(){
        return "finito";
    }
}
```

Comment: I continue to receive 404 not found

Answer (score 0):

for me, your code is working fine and what I see the difference is that one dependancy,

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

[image]

Comment: I try to add the dependency but intellij don't find it

Comment: I continue to receive 404